# Is there any way to verify PDF zoom in / out buttons using selenium?

Tags: java, pdf, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify PDF zoom in and out buttons but seems not able to get it done. I tried to open PDF in new tab and then verify but that is also not working.

I can see some tags and divs when inspect.

I tried diff. xpaths like :

```
//paper-fab[@aria-label='Zoom in']
//paper-feb
```

But it always returns ZERO when I check with list webelement.

Here is example URL :

```
https://pdfobject.com/static.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/):

> Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

I think there is no way to do what you are wanting with just Selenium. If you need to integrate Selenium and Sikuli, you can see this post on SOF: [Calling to a Sikuli script from Python (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198121/calling-to-a-sikuli-script-from-python-selenium/20366782#20366782) . It can give some ideas for you. Yet, maybe you can read a bit about the [Robot class](https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html).

I hope this helps.