# start selenium chromedriver with enabled extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run chromedriver with [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib) plugin. I downloaded the plugin as `.crx` and I initialized browser with this extension:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('/path/to/extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

The extension is correctly loaded in browser but is not enabled.

[image: not enabled extension screenshot]

In order to enable the extension you have to click the extension icon which is outside of DOM.

[image: enabled extension]

Is there any way to perform this kind of action.

Comment: Have your tried with configuring the extension enbale settings in a common profile and loading the profile using ChromeOptions?

Comment: No, I haven't tried this yet but sounds pretty clever. Is it possible to start `chromedriver` and use specific google account as chrome account?

Comment: I am not aware of it.

Comment: I tried the same with a different extension and it's by default enabled for me. Can you try it with a different extension. When you use `AddExtension` method, it should be by default enabled, unless you have other switches like `--disable-extension` added in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done via Selenium. One quick way to do this would be to use [win32 api](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api.html) to simulate a click on the coordinates of your extension button on your screen.

First of all find the coordinate of the extension button on your screen. You can use tool like [this](http://www.breakthrusoftware.com/html/onlinedocs/kb/installkb/ScreenCoordTool.html). I, myself found a rough idea of the location by comparing to the coordinate of my DOM immediately below the button through [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/coordinates/bpflbjmbfccblbhlcmlgkajdpoiepmkd) chrome extension.

Then, use below code to simulate a click on that location:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import win32api, win32con

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('//path to crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='path to chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
click(1317,51) # the coordinates of the button on my 1366 x 768 screen after maximizing. 

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

Additionally you can check out [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). It uses image recognition to identify and perform actions on any desired element on the screen. You first have to take the screenshot of your button and then perform a click function on it inside your sikuli script. After that, you can trigger your sikuli script from python by following suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198121/calling-to-a-sikuli-script-from-python-selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is worked for me on Ubuntu(Linux). So I had done with this

---

**Installation of required packages:**

```
-> sudo apt install libx11-dev
Note: install above "libx" package according to your distro

-> pip install selenium PyUserInput
```

**Note: After installing PyUserInput, you should have pymouse and pykeyboard modules in your python path.**

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pymouse import PyMouse

m = PyMouse()
executable_path = "/home/username/python/chromedriver"
# Note: replace your chromedriver path with above

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_of_extension.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()

m.click(1317,51)
```

Thanks